# Recursion to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, recursion

How could I convert this recursive C# code to JavaScript?

```
bool IsVisibleForExposure => TotalExposure.HasValue || Children.Any(i => i.IsVisibleForExposure);
```

I tried with Lodash and seems not to be working:

```
getIsVisibleForExposure(item: ILimitItem) {
 let result = item.totalExposure !== null || _.some(item.children, i => this.getIsVisibleForExposure(i));
 return result;
}
```

The data structure is something like below:

#### JavaScript

```
interface ILimitItem {
  totalExposure: number;
  children: ILimitItem[]
  ...
}
```

#### C#

```
class LimitItem {
   int? TotalExposure { get; set; }
   LimitItem[] Children { get; set; }
   bool IsVisibleForExposure => TotalExposure.HasValue || Children.Any(i => i.IsVisibleForExposure);
}
```

I basically need to know if an ILimitItem object or any of its children (with the children property) have the totalExposure NOT NULL.

Below is sample data, but it of course will be a much more complex hierarchy or tree structure.

```
const data: ILimitItem = [
  {
    totalExposure: null,
    chilren: [
       {
          totalExposure: null
          children: [
              totalExposure: 100
              children: []
          ]
       }
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: TotalExposure  is not nullable my friend

Comment: Provide some mock data please.

Comment: Please fix your post - your C# code doesn't compile as posted (as per earlier comment, `int TotalExposure` isn't declared nullable), nor is there an `interface` keyword in JS (is this a TypeScript snippet?)

Comment: @CoolBots - Yes, It's clearly TypeScript. And the TypeScript works fine. But without clarity on the expectation, there is no way to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1. You want to return `true` if the root or any nested `TotalExposure` has any value assigned
2. Or return `false` if any `TotalExposure` is not set
3. And TotalExposure may be set to `null` or any `falsy` value

Then this code will do what you expect:

```js
interface ILimitItem {
  totalExposure: number;
  children: ILimitItem[]
}

function getIsVisibleForExposure(item: ILimitItem) {
  return !!item.totalExposure || 
            item.children.some(i => getIsVisibleForExposure(i));
}

const data: ILimitItem = {
  totalExposure: null,
  children: [{
    totalExposure: null,
    children: []
  }]
}

let result = getIsVisibleForExposure(data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is the difference between !!item.totalExposure and item.totalExposure !== null?

Comment: Two negation operators (`!!`) together will coerce any variable to a Boolean based on [JavaScript's truthy/falsy rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) - in comparison, `!==null` is testing with specificity that some value is exactly not equal to `null` and only `null` without taking into account the other falsey value posibilities.

Comment: Here is the reference for the use of the "Double NOT" logical operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#Double_NOT_!!